# HTTP Requester Connctor in Mule

Tags: https, salesforce, mule

I am facing an issue while trying to make a POST call to Salesforce Endpoint through Mule HTTP requester connector to get token in my common flow. Along with endpoint URL, I am passing 5 query parameter.

For different services, I am using this common flow to get Token. But for different services, response is inconsistent.
Sometimes its works perfectly fine and sometimes its responding with Error code **431-Request Header Fields Too Large**. And even sometimes its gives response as **Error sending HTTP request**.

Error code 431 says Header fields are too large but I am not sending single Header while making a call.

I have checked TLS version as well.

How can I solve my this issue?

Comment: Its working fine now by just removing one outbound property which is Mule Session. Even I did not get this, how its working by just removing this property. Does it matters in such cases?

Comment: Mule serialises the session across transports, your error suggests that the recipient server decided that header content was too large, so declined the request. The size of that header depends on the session variables in the flow when it makes the HTTP request. There is no harm in removing this property from the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [HTTP wire logging](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging) you will be able to see the HTTP request in the log and inspect which headers might be too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already tried with these logs to check what are the parameters are going in request. But It also says that its passing any headers.